# Wrapping libusb library in C++

Tags: c++, c, libusb, word-wrap

I want to use the libusb library in my C++ application. I have created classes which wraps libusb functions. You can see that libusb API is split to eight sections:

http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/modules.html

For me the most necessary sections are:

- Device handling and enumeration
- Synchronous device I/O
- Library initialization/deinitialization
- Miscellaneous

I have also split the "Device handling and enumeration" section into "Device Info" and "Device Handling". To use libusb functions it is need to initialize the libusb library (call `libusb_init` function), store its initialized `libusb_context *` somewhere, next - call functions (`libusb_get_device_list`, `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid`) to obtain and store somewhere "device pointer" (in libusb known as `libusb_device*` or `libusb_device_handle*`), and then finally call functions for obtaining device info or performing some USB transfers (for instance: `libusb_set_configuration`, `libusb_get_bus_number`). Note, that these functions require "device pointer": `libusb_device_handle*` or `libusb_device_*` as first parameter. You can see whole process of initializing/opening/controlling device here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/

Currently my solution consists of following classes:

- LibusbInfoAPI: provides functions to obtain device information
- LibusbControlAPI: provides functions to control device
- LibusbHandlingAPI: creates devices, destroys, manages them, and stores `libusb_context *`, `libusb_device *`, `libusb_device_handle *`

LibusbControlAPI header:

```
class LibusbControlAPI
{
    public:
        int GetConfiguration(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int& activeConfiguration);
        int SetConfiguration(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int targetConfiguration);

        int ClaimInterface(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int interfaceNumber);
        int ReleaseInterface(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int interfaceNumber);
        int SetInterfaceAlternateSetting(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int interfaceNumber, int alternateSetting);

        int ClearHalt(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, USBEndpoint endpoint);

        int SendControlTransfer(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle,
                uint8_t bmRequestType,
                uint8_t bRequest,
                uint16_t wValue,
                uint16_t wIndex,
                unsigned char * buffer,
                uint16_t wLength,
                unsigned int timeout);

        int SendInterruptTransfer(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle,
                USBEndpoint endpoint,
                unsigned char * buffer,
                int length,
                int & transferred,
                unsigned int timeout);

        int SendBlukTransfer(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle,
                USBEndpoint endpoint,
                unsigned char * buffer,
                int length,
                int & transferred,
                unsigned int timeout);
};
```

Part of cpp file:

```
int LibusbControlAPI::GetConfiguration(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, int & activeConfiguration)
{
    int result;
    int * configuration = nullptr;

    if (!deviceHandle->m_opened)
        return 1;

    result = libusb_get_configuration(deviceHandle->m_libusbData->m_libusbDeviceHandle, configuration);
    if (result != 0)
        return 1;

    activeConfiguration = *configuration;
    return 0;
}
```

Similary for LibusbInfoAPI header I have:

```
class LibusbInfoAPI
{
    public:
        int GetBusNumber(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, uint8_t& busNumber);
        int GetPortNumber(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, uint8_t& portNumber);

        int GetDeviceAddress(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, uint8_t& deviceAddress);
        int GetDeviceSpeed(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, USBSpeed& usbSpeed);

        int GetMaxPacketSize(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, USBEndpoint endpoint, int& maxPacketSize);
        int GetMaxIsoPacketSize(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle, USBEndpoint endpoint, int& isoMaxPacketSize);
};
```

...and LibusbHandlingAPI (in this class I store libusb structures, in `CreateDevice` function I return a pointer which I use for `LibusbControlAPI` and `LibusbInfoAPI`):

```
class LibusbHandlingAPI
{
    private:
        typedef std::vector<DevHandlePtr> DevHandlePtrVect;

        DevHandlePtrVect m_deviceHandleVect;
        LibusbContextPtr m_libusbContext;

    public:
        DevHandlePtr CreateDevice(uint16_t vendorId, uint16_t productId);
        DevHandlePtr CreateDevice(uint16_t vendorId, uint16_t productId, uint8_t busNumber, uint8_t * portNumbers, int portNumbersLength);
        void DestroyDevice(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle);

        int OpenDevice(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle);
        int CloseDevice(DevHandlePtr deviceHandle);

        int InitializeLibrary(SystemLibraryLogLevel logLevel);
        void DestroyLibrary(void);
};
```

So, my questions are:

- Is it good solution/class design? What do you think?
- What are yours propositions/suggestions?
- How can I improve it? What should I change?
- What classes should I create/remove?

Comment: This looks like something for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, I have moved topic to codereview.stackexchange.com